# Why did the release statement here crashes the app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, http

```
NSError *theError = nil;
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"password", @"userId", nil];
NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:passwordTextField.text, userNameTextField.text, nil];
NSDictionary *requestDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];

NSString *JSONString =[requestDictionary JSONRepresentation]; 
NSData *JSONData =[JSONString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"JSONString :%@", JSONString); 
NSLog(@"JSONData :%@", JSONData); 

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://153.20.32.74/11AprP306/passenger/jsonitem"]];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:JSONData]; 
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSURLResponse *theResponse =[[NSURLResponse alloc]init];
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&theResponse error:&theError];   
NSLog(@"response : %@", theResponse);
NSLog(@"error : %@", theError);
NSLog(@"data : %@", data);
NSMutableString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"string: %@", string);
[string release];
//[theResponse release]; // this statement crashes the app
```

Has it got something with to do with this statement :`NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&theResponse error:&theError];`
I see a `&` symbol used. What does it means?

Answer (score 3):

I'll post this as a new answer as you edited your question.

You are doing it the wrong way.

It is the responsability of `sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:` to create the response for you (or the error if something went wrong)

This is why you need to pass a pointer to `theResponse` and a pointer to `theError`

When the call to `sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:` is done, `theResponse` will be created and most importantly `autoreleased` (by `sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error`) !!

So in the end you are back to the autorelease/over release issue.

The correct code is:

```
NSURLResponse *theResponse = nil; // no need to init it will be done later on
NSError *theError = nil; // no need to init either
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request 
                                     returningResponse:&theResponse
                                                 error:&theError];   

if (aError != nil) { } // handle error
else {} // handle your response data

//no need to release theResponse
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you autorelease `theResponse` when you instantiate it, so releasing it twice is causing your problem.  Either don't make the `autorelease` call or don't make the `release` call.

Personally, I'd get rid of the `autorelease`.  `release` gives finer-grained control over the run of your program.

Oh, and the `&` there is nothing to worry about -- it just passes the *address* of the variable it proceeds.  In this case, you need to pas an `NSURLResponse**`.  Since you have an `NSURLResponse*`, you pass a *reference* to it.

Comment: sorry, the autorelease statement was not suppose to be there. I added in to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `theResponse` has sent the message `autorelease` in:

```
NSURLResponse *theResponse =[[[NSURLResponse alloc]init] autorelease];
```

If you `release` an object that has been `autoreleased` you will cause your application to crash for the Garbage Collector will over release the object.

The `&` simply means "give me the address of `theError` and `theResponse` (basically you are passing a pointer of pointer which is required by the method `sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:`)

```
+ (NSData *)sendSynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request 
                 returningResponse:(NSURLResponse **)response
                             error:(NSError **)error
```

The `NSURLResponse **` and `NSError **` means 'address of address' so give them only `theError` or `theResponse` (without the `&`) would simply give the method 'their address' when it is expecting something else.

Comment: Sorry, the autorelease statement was not suppose to be there. I added in to solve the problem

Comment: I just wanted to know why if I called release method manually instead, it will crashes.

Comment: ok i understand then you are doing it the wrong way i will post the correct answer but you should mention that you have edited your question in the question itself because now, someone getting into your problem will not understand our previous answers